# How do I fit a function to a candle plot TH2 in ROOT?

Tags: root-framework

I've collected test data for a system and would like to fit a line to the linear portion of the system.

Here's my current plot, which is very barebones:

[image: Current plot]

This was generated by drawing a TH2D with the CANDLE option, which gives nice error bars.  However, neither of the two obvious [TH2 fit options](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTH2.html#a9bfd1ea19dee46c25861d58ee60eaa3d), both of which take slices and fit to slices, seems to be able to fit a line to this candle plot.  The only clear solution I see is to make an array of TH1Ds corresponding to my X axis, filling them, then extracting their means and standard deviations and using those in a TGraphErrors plot, which makes fitting easy.

Is there a way to fit a line directly in the candle plot?  If not, is there a more elegant solution than the one that I outlined above?

Comment: looking at the implementation of the candle plot ( https://root.cern.ch/root/html534/src/THistPainter.cxx.html#BUlqjE ) it draws bunch of lines and boxes for the quantiles, etc. So what you see on the screen is not stored in any useful form for the fit. I guess you'll have to redo what the candle plot does, store it as TGraphErrors and fit it.

Comment: "Elegant" is hard to come by in the ROOT framework: the framework is designed for more for backward compatibility than anything else, and the authors are generally quite dismissive of the idea that "real physicists" would care about things like pretty code (which is true, if they break something they'll get a lot of heat from CERN). My advice to users is to do whatever works, if you want elegance work with scipy.